# BeautifulSoup4 and Requests Module 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web scraping with python and am having a problem with the weather web scraping script I wrote. Here is the whole code 'weather.py':

```
#! python3 

import bs4, requests 


weatherSite = requests.get('https://weather.com/en-CA/weather/today/l/eef019cb4dca2160f08eb9714e30f28e05e624bbae351ccb6a855dbc7f14f017')
weatherSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(weatherSite.text, 'html.parser')


weatherLoc = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--location--kyTeL')
weatherTime = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--timestamp--23dfw')
weatherTemp = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--tempValue--3a50n')
weatherCondition = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W')
weatherDet = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--precipValue--3nxCj > span:nth-child(1)')

location = weatherLoc[0].text
time = weatherTime[0].text
temp = weatherTemp[0].text
condition = weatherCondition[0].text
det = weatherDet[0].text

print(location)
print(time)
print(temp + 'C')
print(condition)
print(det)
```

It basically parses the weather information from 'The Weather Channel' and prints it out. This code was working fine yesterday when I wrote it. But, I tried today and it is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\filesAndStuff\weather.py", line 16, in <module>
    location = weatherLoc[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
weatherLoc = weatherSoup.select('.CurrentConditions--location--kyTeL')

# print(weatherLoc)
# []
```

By:

```
weatherLoc = weatherSoup.select('h1[class*="CurrentConditions--location--"]')

# print(weatherLoc)
# [<h1 class="CurrentConditions--location--2_osB">Hamilton, Ontario Weather</h1>]
```

As you can see, your suffix `kYTeL` is not the same for me `2_osB`. You need a partial match on class attribute (`class*=`) (note the `*`)

Comment: Thank youu, this worked! I copied over this syntax for all the other values like so: 

weatherLoc = weatherSoup.select('h1[class*="CurrentConditions--location--"]')
weatherTime = weatherSoup.select('div[class*="CurrentConditions--timestamp--"]')
weatherTemp = weatherSoup.select('span[class*="CurrentConditions--tempValue--"]')
weatherCondition = weatherSoup.select('div[class*="CurrentConditions--phraseValue--"]')
weatherDet = weatherSoup.select('div[class*="CurrentConditions--precipValue--"] > span:nth-child(1)')


This has fixed my problem! Thanks again!